# How to increase JQM append listview performance

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-mobile

I have created 10000 dummy record for a listview and test it performance in 2 set of code .

First Method . use push method and than append to the listview

```
function CreateList(result){
                var i = 0;
                var lstlist=[];
                for(i=0; i< result.length; i++)
                {                                   
                    lstlist.push("<li id='"+result[i].ID+"'><a><img src='"+result[i].Image+"'><h2>"+result[i].Name+" "+ result[i].ID+"</h2><p>"+result[i].Description+"</p></a>");  
                }   

                $("#lv").append(lstlist);
                $("#lv").listview("refresh");                
            }
```

Second Method , Direct append to the listview

```
function CreateList(result){
                var i = 0;
                var lstlist=[];
                for(i=0; i< result.length; i++)
                {                                   
                    $("#lv").append("<li id='"+result[i].ID+"'><a><img src='"+result[i].Image+"'><h2>"+result[i].Name+" "+ result[i].ID+"</h2><p>"+result[i].Description+"</p></a>");   
                }                       

                $("#lv").listview("refresh");                
            }
```

Both method seems like not performing well , is that any better method ?

Answer (score 3):

10000 dummy records is waaaaay to much for jQuery Mobile 1.3. Listview scrolling performances starts to degrade even after 100+ elements. jQuery Mobile 1.4 fares much batter but you will still have a problem with 200-300 + listview elements.

Not to mention, Kendo UI, PhoneJS or Sencha Touch can't handle that much listview elements.

Best course of action would be to implement pagination in your listview.

**jQuery Mobile Listview Pagination Plugin**

Github link: https://github.com/stakbit/jQuery-Mobile-Listview-Pagination-Plugin

Official support: jQuery Mobile 1.3

Demo http://listomatic.stakbit.com/

Or to implement Pull-to-Refresh. You can do it on your own or you can use:

**iScrollView plugin**

Github link: https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview

Official support: jQuery Mobile 1.3 (it even works with 1.4)